# comes with and side item

Tags: phrases

I am confused with following phrases, how these two phrases work,please help me. Thank you!

Match them with their meanings

> 1. comes with
> 2. side item
>
> (a) to be included with a meal
>
> (b) added to, or along with the main part of a

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What do you mean by *how these two phrases work*?

Comment: Can you give full sentences with them? Or is this the full question from a test?

Answer (score 1):

*1* will go with *a* because if said item comes with a meal, it will be included with a meal. For example, if a menu said a steak comes with a baked potato, you will expect the baked potato with your steak at no additional cost. A side item (*2*) is usually an add on to the main meal (*b*). So you can add on a baked potato to your steak for a bit of extra money. However, *2* and *b* could also go together in the same way that *1* goes with *a*. A side item of your choice could be included with your steak.